# How do I get the user object after the successful payment in stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment

I have integrated stripe into my website to accept card payments.
I have this route to know about a successful or failed payment which is working fine and is giving me the event object with all the information needed.

```
routes.post(
  "/webhook",
  express.raw({ type: "application/json" }),
  (request, response) => {
    let event = request.body;

    const endpointSecret =
      "whsec_66266181ad61dd3ccde280aaddc27ba14f2fabea8a4d71761804e72581d31436";
    if (endpointSecret) {
      const signature = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
          request.body,
          signature,
          endpointSecret
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
        return response.sendStatus(400);
      }
    }

    switch (event.type) {
      case "charge.succeeded":
        console.log({ event });
        const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
        console.log(
          `PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} was successful!`
        );
        break;

      case "charge.failed":
        console.log({ event });
        const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
    }

    response.send().end();
  }
);
```

The problem is that how do I get the user information. When an event is fired on my stripe dashboard, It only gives me the information of the payments. But I want the information of the user also like the username to search in the database and do some changes. But that is not being provided. The stripe event object do provide me with the name of the card user but that is not needed. I need the username of the user on my website to do some changes.
Please help me with that.

Comment: I think you should associate stripe_transaction_id and user_id in you DB transaction table. When you receive stripe event regarding transaction then find transaction in your DB.

Comment: If you use PaymentIntent, you should listen to `payment_intent.*` related events. During PaymentIntent creation, you can include your own defined user ID under [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-metadata) parameter, which will be included in `payment_intent.*` events later. You will use this user ID to retrieve your internal user data.